Excluding Weekends with Carbon
I have a helper that is supposed to exclude weekends from a cauculation.
The created_at date for example is
2024-08-20 22:54:27 and today is 2024-08-26 9:54:27 = 5 Days 9 Hours
When I run this script is returns 4 Days 9 Hours
Can someone shed any light into why it is omitting 1 day in the calculation??
if (!function_exists('getTimeInReceiptStatusLessWeekends')) {
    function getTimeInReceiptStatusLessWeekends(Receipt $receipt): string
    {
        // Assuming Receipt has a relationship to Activity
        $activity = $receipt->activities()->latest()->first(); // Get the latest activity

        if (!$activity) {
            return 'No activity found'; // Handle cases where no activity is found
        }

        // Get the next activity (status change)
        $nextActivity = Activity::where('subject_type', $activity->subject_type)
            ->where('subject_id', $activity->subject_id)
            ->where('created_at', '>', $activity->created_at)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
            ->first();

        // Determine end time for the current status
        $endTime = $nextActivity ? new Carbon($nextActivity->created_at) : Carbon::now();

        // Start time is the creation time of the activity
        $startTime = new Carbon($activity->created_at);

        // Calculate the duration excluding weekends
        $totalDays = $startTime->diffInDaysFiltered(function (Carbon $date) {
            return !$date->isWeekend(); // Exclude weekends
        }, $endTime);

        // Calculate the total hours/minutes excluding weekends
        $totalHours = $startTime->diffFiltered(CarbonInterval::hour(), function (Carbon $date) {
            return !$date->isWeekend(); // Exclude weekends
        }, $endTime);

        // If you want to return the result in hours
        $hours = $totalHours;

        // Or if you want to return the result in a human-readable format (days and hours)
        $duration = CarbonInterval::days($totalDays)
            ->hours($totalHours % 24)
            ->forHumans(['parts' => 2]);

        return $duration;
    }
}


your $hours is not used..
